# Prevent Windows 10 updates from losing my hibernation session?

Tags: windows-10, updates, automatic-updates, hibernation

I'm running a Dell XPS 9350 on Windows 10 (OS Build 10586.218), and have experienced the following issue:

1. Windows session running with various apps open, Chrome, etc
2. I close laptop lid (power options configured to sleep on this action)
3. Machine **sleeps**
4. After 180 minutes, machine **hibernates** (power options also configured to do this on battery so is expected)
5. I open lid, and press the power button to turn the machine on again.
6. Windows starts to boot, but I get a screen showing a percentage of Windows Updates that are being installed! The screen shows a Dell logo, but I suspect that's just an OEM customisation to Windows. A mouse cursor is visible at this step.
7. **After updates installed, my hibernation session is lost** - I am back to a clean boot to Windows.

Windows Updates are set to Automatic.

Clearly, something is not right here! If a machine is in hibernation, updates shouldn't be installed when the power is turned back on.

Have searched on Google and within these forums and can't see anyone else with this issue.

Does anyone know how to stop this behaviour, or is it some sort of Windows 10 bug?

Answer (score 7):

I had that issue which was resolved by:

1) Start gpedit.msc

2) Computer Configuration => Administrative Templates => Windows Components => Windows Update

3) There is the setting "Enabling Windows Update Power Management to automatically wake up the system to install scheduled updates". Turn it off.

There are some settings as well in a more common place:

Power Options => Click on the plan selected => advanced power settings => Sleep > Allow wake timers

**From the documentation regarding that setting:**

"Automatic Updates will wake the system to install updates if the following are true:

Automatic Updates is configured to automatically install updates.

The system is in hibernation at the scheduled installation time and there are updates to install, or if an installation deadline occurs."

Comment: It should be noted that gpedit.msc is not available on Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways Windows wakes from hibernation or sleep :

- By devices like Keyboard, Mouse or LAN

Change this in device manager e.g.

Controlpanel -> device manager -> keyboard -> yourkeyb -> power management -> deselect   'allow this device..'

- By timers in the powerplan

Settings -> Power and sleep - > Additional power settings -> 
Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings - > Sleep -> Allow wake timers -> disable

- By Microsoft to install updates etc.

If you open a Powershell (run as admin) you can see the tasks that can
wake the computer and reboot :

```
Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}
```

The most wake ups are caused by the UpdateOrchestrator.
Open Powershell as admin and run :

```
  SCHTASKS /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" /DISABLE
```

Any other can be disabled through the app Task-Schedular. (No detailed
instructions here) Note that Microsoft re-enables the UpdateOrchestrator
often. So you actualy need to run above every time you put the computer into hibernation.

To check if there is anything left that can wake up the computer
run this in the powershell.

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed

powercfg /WAKETIMERS
```

I have written a script i use on my devices to go
into hibernation, maybe post it here later.